# Making a link confirmation with Jquery alert dialogs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the following situation:

-A website with a table where every row represents an item, and for each item there is a link to make certain action (with GET vars).

So, I'm using the [Jquery Alert Dialogs Plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) for making a confirmation message, but i can't get to follow the link after the user presses 'OK'

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var go = false;
$(document).ready( function() {
 $("a.disable ").click( function() {
  if(go == false) {
   jConfirm('Are u sure?', 'Confirm action', function(r) {
    if (r == true)
     {
      go = true;
      alert( $(this).attr['href']);

     }

   });
});
</script>
```

Note: I'm using alert for testing, but that should be a document.location
Note 1: the alert() gives me 'undefined' :(
Note 2: I'm using multiple buttons with the same class (number of buttons depends on items count)

HTML:

`<a href="disable?action=disable&id=5" class="button red disable">Disable</a>`
Note: button repeated with different get vars

Also, if I use "a.disable" selector in the alert(), I got the URL of the first button in the page, so doesn't work :<

Thanks!

Comment: You probably meant `$(this).attr('href')`.

Comment: Just throwing in a selector into an `alert`, of course, "doesn't work". You'd have to loop over the results that you get and `alert` each one separately. Did you expect `alert` to automagically combine multiple strings in a way that telepathically does what you want?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var go = false;
$(document).ready( function() {
 $("a.disable").click( function() {

  var $this = $(this); // cached the object $(this)

  if(go == false) {
   jConfirm('Are u sure?', 'Confirm action', function(r) {
    if (r == true)
     {
      go = true;

      alert( $this.attr('href')); // use the cached object

     }

   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: omg didn't noticed about attr(), maybe too much php for this night (arrays) thanks :)